# delete reference to a container in member function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, containers

I have  `class A`, then I made a vector of `class A`;
`std::vector<A> b`, and i initialize it correctly.

I have one member function of another class, which has a member pointer which point to a
vector of A;

In this class, I also have a member function, and inside this member function. 
I fist build a reference to the vector of class A, and initialize it use the deference of the pointer, The reason is the member reference can only assign value once, so I use pointer, but inside the member function, the syntax of reference is more clean.

the question is, in the member function, if i delete the reference to that vector,  does it only delete the reference or delete the whole container the pointer point to.  The container contain object not pointer.

Thanks

Comment: You are mixing references and pointers. Please provide a code, or a more clear description. You can't delete a reference, it's not technically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the reference goes out of scope it's not going to destroy the original object.

I assume this is the situation:

```
class A {};

class B
{
     std::vector<A>* pA;

public:
     B( std::vector<A>* p ): pA(p) {}

     void foo()
     {
          std::vector<A>& arr = *pA;
          //do stuff with arr
          // Arr and pA are still valid after the end of this function
     }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> Arr;
    Arr.push_back( A() );

    B b( &Arr );
    b.foo();
}
```

Comment: If it is bound to a temporary it does, but that's probably not this case.

Comment: Thanks,  It's not bound to a temporary.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide an example but with what you provided, it's already a big no no!

If you store a `std::vector<A>` you're storing actual objects of type A. When your vector grows, the items will be *copied* to a new memory location, therefore keeping pointers or references to items inside a vector of objects won't work as you expect.

Consider storing pointers instead (`std::vector<A*>`)

Deleting your pointer to a `std::vector<A>` should delete everything. If you switch to `std::vector<A*>` you should delete every object in the vector then delete the vector.